# How to send a single email to a contact from salesforce using Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We have recently connected our Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud instances using marketing cloud connect. I am trying to see if we can send one-off email to specific contact records from the Contact detail page in salesforce.

I can see a "New Email Send" button on the Contact page under the "Email Sends" related list but from this screen it asks me two choose a recipient as a report or a campaign. I just want to send this email to a single contact and not to an entire list.

I went through the online documentation and it seems that it is possible to send single emails to contacts and leads, as mentioned here -

**Send Single Email -
Follow these steps to send a single Marketing Cloud email from within Sales or Service Cloud.**

1. In Sales or Service Cloud, navigate to a lead, contact, person account, or campaign.
2. Click Send Marketing Cloud Email.
3. To access Marketing Cloud emails, click Find. Select an email. Select a From email address.
4. Select a Reply-to email address.

[Link to the above help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_send_single_email.htm&type=5)

I am unable to locate this button "*Send Marketing Cloud Email*" anywhere on the contact detail page, contacts tab or under any Contact related lists. Is there any specific setting I need to enable to get this up and running ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I was able to dig this out from one of the help pages -

The "Send Marketing Cloud Email" wasn't a button but a link on a VF component available for the Contacts detail page.

Go to **Contacts > Edit Layout > Visualforce Pages > ContactActions**

Add this and you will be able to send single emails from the contact page.